# Why was Jimmy Hoffa so confident that posessing compromising evidence would protect him?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-irishman

In [*The Irishman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Irishman), Jimmy Hoffa is given an unambiguous, final warning by Frank Sheeran that he would be whacked by the mob if he does not give up his attempts to reclaim his power atop [the Teamsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Brotherhood_of_Teamsters).

However, he dismisses the warning. At 2:20:10:

> *Jimmy*:  They wouldn't dare ... That's fairy tales ... If something funny happens to me, they're done. ... Because I got files. I got
> proof. I got records. Tapes. Any time I want, they'll be gone. These
> Guinea motherfuckers will spend the rest of their lives in jail, and
> they know it.
>
> *Frank*: That's what they're concerned about.

What was Jimmy counting on? Clearly, he wouldn't be able to use any of the files/records/tapes if dead. Neither he seems to have arranged any dead man's switch.

Was he just erratic and dumb?

If he wasn't, why did it not work (to either save his life or jail the mobsters)?

Comment: When he's dead other people will find his files and proofs. For all they know, he's lodged them with a lawyer or arranged for them to be posted to the DA on his death

Comment: @Valorum Was that so? Did it happen upon his disappearance / presumed death?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, but the threat is there, clearly. As to why it didn't work, knowing who did it would help us, but alas his disappearance is unsolved.

Comment: @Valorum The question is about the film character, not the real person. In the film, we know who did it.

Comment: I think the title might be more readable if it said something like, "Why was Jimmy Hoffa so confident that possessing compromising evidence would protect him?" Or if you want to include complacent, then maybe something like, "Why was Jimmy Hoffa so complacent that he thought that possessing compromising evidence would protect him?" I didn't make an edit because I didn't want to accidentally change your intended meaning.